# How to add 3-dimensional to matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm new in Python.

I have a simple Python code:

```
A0 = np.zeros([100,100,40], dtype=np.uint8)
```

I want to add a 3-dimensional object(example cube) to matrix.

I know Matlab code is:

```
A0(5:45, 5:45, 3:17) = 1;
```

Anyone know how to do it?

Best

Comment: It's the same. Use `[`,`]` instead of `(`,`)` and you are done.

Comment: Just watch out since MATLAB starts indexing from 1, but numpy starts from 0. Since your question is unlikely to help future readers, I suggest that you delete it.